# wicket framework

Tags: wicket

I'm now working on a software and decided to choose **apache wicket** to be my framework, but we're a team and each one of us uses a different Operating system.

I wanted to know if wicket is compatible with which operating systems?

Answer (score 11):

Erm,... Wicket is a Java library. So if you can use Java on your OS you can use Wicket.

Comment: To be more precise, Wicket requires Java version 1.5 or higher.

Comment: Java version requirement does depend on which version of Wicket though.